# How To Access Predefined Class Attributes From IDA Pro After Loading The Binary Without Debugger Attached To Process

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly, debugging, binary

I have this class with constructor offsets and attributes:

```
public class example 
{
    // Fields
    public float Attribute_1 = 1.5f; // 0x8
    public int Attribute_2 = 102 ; // 0xC

    
    // RVA: 0x198EF70 Offset: 0x198EF70 VA: 0x9BF8EF70
    public void .ctor() { }
}
```

The question is how to access predefined attributes `Attribute_1` and  `attribute_2` in IDA.

Comment: Many pieces of information are missing from this question, such as: what language is that? (.NET CLR?) What do you mean, "access" those attributes? Also, IDA is a disassembler, whereas you are showing high-level code. Don't expect IDA to decompile the binary into the language from your snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in IDA **Jump to the constructor address**, in my case `0x198ef70,` then translate to **pseudocode**, and you will find all the attributes with their values related to **`example` class.**